# PHP Button not working(number systems converter)

Tags: php

I have this little project to make a converter between the 4  number systems using PHP I wrote the functions for the conversion and they are working perfectly but I when I tried to input the numbers using a little forum nothing seemed to be working

The main code

```
if (empty ($_POST ["input"])) {  $_POST ["input"] = "";}
$input=$_POST ["input"] ;

echo '<div id = "header">';
    echo '<center><h2><font color="#FFFFFF">Zahlensysteme-Umrechner</font></h2></center>';
echo '</div>';echo "<br>";
$name           = "";
$action         = $_SERVER ["PHP_SELF"];
$method         = "post";
$enctype        = "";
$target         = "";
echo formular_beginn ($name, $action, $method, $target, $enctype);


# Auswahlmenü Farbe der Kugeln
# Voreinstellung (wenn erforderlich)
if (!isset ($_POST ["Zahlensysteme"])) $_POST ["Zahlensysteme"] = "binary";
$name           = "Zahlensysteme";
$values         = array ("binary", "decimal", "hexadecimal", "octal",);
$selected_value = $_POST ["Zahlensysteme"];
$extra_html     = "";
$size           = 1;
$multiple       = 0;
echo auswahlliste ($name, $values, $selected_value, $size, $multiple, $extra_html);
echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\n";

$name="";
$value=$_POST ["input"];
$size ="";
$maxlength="";
$readonly ="";
$extra_html="";
echo textfeld_einzeilig ($name, $value, $size, $maxlength, $readonly, $extra_html);

echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\n";
$name           = "";
$type           = "submit";
$value          = "Anzeigen";
$extra_html     = "";
echo klickbutton ($name, $type, $value, $extra_html);
echo formular_ende ();
###################################################

if ($_POST ["Zahlensysteme"] == "binary")
  {
  $input   = $_POST ["input"];       # Anzahl der Kugeln (Breite)
BiToHex($input);
echo "<br>";
BiToDez ($input);
echo "<br>";
BiToOkt($input);
  }

if ($_POST ["Zahlensysteme"] == "decimal")
  {
  $input   = $_POST ["input"];       # Anzahl der Kugeln (Breite)
DezToBi ($input);
echo "<br>";
DezToHex($input);
echo "<br>";
DezToOkt ($input);
  }

if ($_POST ["Zahlensysteme"] == "hexadecimal")
  {
  $input   = $_POST ["input"];       # Anzahl der Kugeln (Breite)
HexToBi ($input);
echo "<br>";
HexToDez($input);
echo "<br>";
HexToOkt ($input);
  }

if ($_POST ["Zahlensysteme"] == "octal")
  {
  $input   = $_POST ["input"];       # Anzahl der Kugeln (Breite)
OktToBi ($input);
echo "<br>";
OktToDez($input);
echo "<br>";
OktToHex ($input);
  }
```

Functions

```
function auswahlliste ($name, $values, $selected_value, $size, $multiple, $extra_html)
{
$liste = "<select name=\"$name\" size=\"1\" $extra_html>\n";
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof ($values); $i++)
  {
  $liste.= "<option value = \"".$values [$i]."\" ";
  if ($values [$i] == $selected_value) $liste.= "selected";
  $liste.= ">".$values [$i]."\n";
  }
$liste.= "</select>\n";
return $liste;
}


function klickbutton ($name, $type, $value, $extra_html) # Herkömmlicher Button
{
 return "<input type=\"$type\" name=\"$name\" value=\"$value\" $extra_html>" ; 
}


function formular_beginn ($name, $action, $method, $target, $enctype)
{
return "<form action=\"$action\" method=\"$method\" target=\"$target\" name=\"$name\" enctype=\"$enctype\"> \n";
}




function formular_ende ()
{
return "</form>\n"; 
}




function textfeld_einzeilig ($name, $value, $size, $maxlength, $readonly, $extra_html)
{

return "<input type=\"Text\" name=\"$name\" value=\"$value\" size=\"$size\" maxlength=\"$maxlength\" $readonly $extra_html> \n";
}
```

And the conversion functions

http://www.codesend.com/view/a5c8a858d2eb35a6eca35fd6957d1282/

Comment: For converting between bases I suggest using http://php.net/base_convert.

Comment: @d3L the point from this project is to see if I can create such functions from scratch